# ASP.NET 2.0 files work in one folder, but NOT in another

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, permissions, frameworks, asp.net-2.0

I have created an ASP.NET application for a client and all the files are in a folder on their D drive.

Now it is time to go production, so I copied all my files and folders to their existing classic ASP folder on the same drive.

When I browse to the application it fails to launch.

The only difference I can see is that the development site does not require HTTPS like the production site.

I also made sure all the permissions are the same on both folders.
I also made sure that the GAC has read rights using the aspnet_regiis tool.

I am at the end of my debug knowledge, could someone please help me out.

Here are the error messages I get from the application event log.

```
Failed to initialize the AppDomain:/LM/W3SVC/3/Root

Exception: System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException
Message: Exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' was thrown.
StackTrace:    at System.Web.Configuration.ErrorRuntimeConfig.ErrorConfigRecord.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigRecord.GetLkgSection(String configKey)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfigLKG.GetSectionObject(String sectionName)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSection(String sectionName, Type type, ResultsIndex index)
   at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.get_HostingEnvironment()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.StartMonitoringForIdleTimeout()
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironment(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)
   at System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationManager.CreateAppDomainWithHostingEnvironmentAndReportErrors(String appId, IApplicationHost appHost, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters)

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

------------------------
Failed to execute the request because the ASP.NET process identity does not have read permissions to the global assembly cache. Error: 0x80131902 

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
-------------------------

aspnet_wp.exe  (PID: 4568) stopped unexpectedly.

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

**Here is the web error message:**

```
Server Application Unavailable 
The web application you are attempting to access on this web server is currently unavailable.  Please hit the "Refresh" button in your web browser to retry your request. 

Administrator Note: An error message detailing the cause of this specific request failure can be found in the application event log of the web server. Please review this log entry to discover what caused this error to occur.
```

Thank you for your help,

Steve

Comment: Just to make sure you're not missing the obvious: Have you made sure that you have activated ASP.NET (and the right version) i IIS? Have you made the folder an Application, or at least a Virtual directory?

Comment: Yes I have, the app where I copied the files to is a classic ASP app and I made sure that ASP.NET 2.0 is enabled in the tab.

Thank you for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Some things worth checking:

- Folder permissions to ensure that the IIS worker process has access to the folder the files are in
- If the files are in a folder - that the folder is set up as a virtual directory in IIS and you have clicked the create button in the IIS control panel to create an application.

Comment: I have done all that, I actually went overboard and gave EVERYONE full access to ALL folders just to see if I get it to work, and NOTHING. I have no idea what to do. Why would one folder work and the other does not?

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure the worker process account is configured properly. Try running the following in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727` folder:

> `aspnet_regiis -ga <worker_process_account_name>`

Comment: Is the worker_process_account_name the account under which the app is running? Would that be ASPNET account? I am sorry I ask, I never really had to deal with this before.

Comment: @steve - 1. open the website properties and click on the 'Home Directory' tab. Note the name of the 'Application Pool' (it's a dropdown listbox). 2. Open the Application Pools node of the IIS manager tree, browse to the application pool noted in (1). Right-click and open the Application Pool properties and click the Identity tab. What identity is being used?

Comment: They use IIS 6.o, there is no application pool. Thank you very much for your help. I wonder how to solve this mystery.

Comment: @Steve - there must be? Or are they running IIS6 in IIS5 compatibility mode?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody for all you suggestions and help. Since nothing worked and made no sense to me I decided to reinstall the framework and everything is fine now.

Steve